# when using pod install with 1.0.0 instead of 0.39.0, storyboards are not copied to the pod bundle

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec

I'm trying to use a storyboard file inside my pod with the following code:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:bundle];
```

This worked with using `pod _0.39.0_ install`, but not with version 1.0.0 any more.

The podspec-file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name             = "MyPod"
s.version = '1.0.0'
s.summary          = "Summary"
s.description      = <<-DESC
                  ...
                   DESC

s.homepage         = "http://www.myhomepage.com"
s.license          = 'MIT'
s.author           = { "..." => "" }
s.source           = { :git => "https://.../mypod", :tag => s.version.to_s}
s.platform     = :ios, '8.0'
s.requires_arc = true
s.source_files = 'MYPod/**/*.{h,m}' 
s.resources = ["MYPod/**/*.xcassets", "MYPod/**/*.storyboard", "MYPod/**/*.xib"]
s.dependency 'MyDependency', '~> 1.0'
end
```

What do I have to change to have it working with 1.0.0 as well?

Comment: I'm also having this issue. My original theory was that the storyboard is no longer in the same bundle as it was pre 1.0.0, but haven't been able to find a fix yet.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? I had this same issue when using Cocoapods 1.0.0 with Xcode 7.2.1. When I ran on XCode 7.3 this morning, everything works fine.